# System requests on Experience Analytics reports

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, reporting

On an 8.2 new installation I am getting a few Entry and Exit page URL entries on the Experience Analytics reports which I would not expect:

> /api/sitecore/settings/setuserprofilekey
>
> /sitecore/shell/client/speak/assets/lib/ui/1.1/deps/nvd3/nv.d3.min.js.map
>
> /sitecore/shell/client/applications/pathanalyzer/help/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

I've made no modification to the  configurations so the shell site has its enableTracking setting set to false, however those 3 urls come up under the "website" site filter on the dashboard.

Any thoughts on why those are being tracked? I might look into filter them out but I'd like first to understand why they come up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that it might be useful in the future, I ended up contacting the support and solved the problem by:

1. Filtering out such requests using the untrackedPages section of the config
2. Installing a patch to fix a bug specific to the setuserprofilekey entry

Comment: Is the patch available for everyone?

Comment: No. The support team explicitly asks not to share the patch with other customers since they need to validate it against the systems affected. 
However, if you're affected by the same bug you may raise a ticket with them and mention the bug report with reference  number 147688.

Answer (score 2):

Even though `<untrackedPages>` can be used to address your issue, I'd consider skipping the entire execution of request for *.js, *.map and fonts resources by using IgnoreURLPrefix in your web.config

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes" value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|/webresource.axd|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/applications/content manager/telerik.web.ui.dialoghandler.aspx|/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd|/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd|/sitecore/admin/upgrade/|/layouts/testing|/sitecore/service/xdb/disabled.aspx|/sitecore/shell/client/applications/pathanalyzer/help/fonts/*|/sitecore/shell/client/speak/assets/lib/ui/1.1/deps/nvd3/*.map" />
```

This will skip Sitecore request processing pipeline and thus save your precious CPU processing time - unless you're storing those files as Sitecore media assets.

This doesn't address the issue with */api/sitecore/settings/setuserprofilekey*

*Just a note: the issue you're describing is because you're either using your CM to browsing the site and didn't turn off the analytics or you're using co-located CM/CD deployment. In a properly scaled environment, you should not be seeing it.*

I hope it helps.